# Regular Expression For The Language Σ = {0,1}

Tags: regular-expressions, automata

I have an language of `Σ = {0,1}` and need to find the the regular expression of:

1. Set of strings that have no pairs of consecutive zeros
2. Set of strings that contain at most one zero

For the first one I tried

```
(01 + 1)*.(0)
```

For the second I tried

```
(1*0)
```

I kind of feel that this is wrong. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add a list of samples of what should be matched and what should not please?

Comment: It's an homework give by the university, it only mentions what i wrote in the question to make the regular expression based on the lanugage

Comment: The regular expression for the language `L = {0,1}` is `0|1`, but that's a different language than the two languages you describe in the question. Did you maybe mean "languages over the alphabet `Σ = {0, 1}`"?

Comment: @sepp2k yes it was Σ = {0,1} instead of L = {0,1} by bad

Comment: The first one looks right, but I'm not sure about what the syntax `.(0)` means in the formalism you are using. It should refer to an optional zero, is that right? Usually written `[0]` or `0?` or `(|0)` or `(ε + 0)`.

Comment: The second one is wrong. Your regex `(1*0)` matches *exactly* one zero, and only in the end.

Comment: At most one zero: [`\b1*0?1*\b`](//regexr.com/4d7dc)

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution seems fine except for the fact that the last zero has to be optional and that the string `0` has to be accepted as well.

For the second one, you could use `1*0?1*`, because if a string contains a zero, it can be anywhere. In `(1*0)`, there has to be exactly one zero and it has to be at the last position.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the regular expressions for the two points,

For `Set of strings that have no pairs of consecutive zeros` you can use,

```
^(?!.*00)[10]+$
```

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/rnUpCD/1)**

For `Set of strings that contain at most one zero` you can use,

```
^(?=1*0?1*$)[10]+$
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/G4H8WX/1)**